# Thread-safe buffer

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, event-handling

I'm implementing some kind of buffering mechanism:

```
private static readonly ConcurrentQueue<ProductDto> ProductBuffer = new ConcurrentQueue<ProductDto>();

private async void On_ProductReceived(object sender, ProductReceivedArgs e)
{
    ProductBuffer.Enqueue(e.Product);

    if (ProductBuffer.Count >= handlerConfig.ProductBufferSize)
    {
        var products = ProductBuffer.ToList();
        ProductBuffer.Clear();

        await SaveProducts(products);
    }
}
```

And the question is - should I bother to add some kind of lock, to ensure no data is lost (f.e. some other thread will add product after buffer.ToList() and before buffer.Clear(), hypothetically:), or **ConcurrentQueue** will handle all the dirty work for me?

Comment: Yes, you should lock. ConcurrentQueue has no knowledge how or if your code is threadsafe.

Comment: Feels like ConcurrentQueue(Of T).TryDequeue Method (T) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287208(v=vs.110).aspx might be of use perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
if (ProductBuffer.Count < handlerConfig.ProductBufferSize)
    return;

var productsToSave = new List<Product>();
Product dequeued = null;
while(ProductBuffer.TryDequeue(out dequeued))
{
    productsToSave.Add(dequeued);
}
SaveProducts(products);
```

You never `Clear` the queue. You just keep taking things out until it's empty. Or you could stop taking things out when `productsToSave` reaches a certain size, process that list, and then start a new one if you don't want to save too many products at once.

This way it doesn't matter if new items are added to the queue. If they're added while you're reading from the queue, they get read too. If they're added just after you stop reading from the queue, they'll be there and get read the next time the queue gets full and you process it.

The point of a `ConcurrentQueue` is that you can add to it and read from it from multiple threads, with no need for `lock`.

---

If you were to do this:

```
    productsToSave = ProductBuffer.ToList();

    ProductBuffer.Clear();
```

then you would need the `lock` (which would defeat the purpose.) Presumably you're using a `ConcurrentQueue` because multiple threads may be adding items to the queue. If that's the case then it is entirely possible that something could go into the queue in between the execution of those two statements. It wouldn't get added to the list, but it would be deleted by `Clear`. That item would be lost.

Comment: That is a hell of an answer, thanx!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would implement it, I am assuming you do not need to be notified of when the save is finished?

```
private void On_ProductReceived(object sender, ProductReceivedArgs e)
{
    // Variable to hold potential list of products to save
    List<Products> productsToSave;

    // Lock buffer
    lock(ProductBuffer)
    {
        ProductBuffer.Enqueue(e.Product);

        // If it is under size, return immediately
        if (ProductBuffer.Count < handlerConfig.ProductBufferSize)
            return;

        // Otherwise save products, clear buffer, release lock.
        productsToSave = ProductBuffer.ToList();

        ProductBuffer.Clear();
    }

    // Save Produts, 

    SaveProducts(products);
}
```

What if you get 1 product, and don't get anything else, will you not want to save this after some timeout?

I would use something like `Rx` for your use case, especially `IObservable<T>.Buffer(count)`

Comment: That is how my first implementation looked like, then I had moments of hesitation after reading how cool and awesome those Concurrent* collections are :)

Comment: No, I don't need to be notified.

Comment: @liri2006 I would use Rx, allows you to be more explicit and not need to handle this yourself

Comment: "What if you get 1 product,"

I'm doing Save of all remaining buffer after the Receive (which has this event handler) method finished.

Comment: There's no reason to use a `ConcurrentQueue` if you're just going to lock around all access to the queue.

Comment: Rx sound like a great idea, might worth a try.